# Where is Electropus?

Tags: discussion, electropus

Will he ever return or is this decor permanent?

Is Electropus under the same community license as the rest of chiphacker?

[image]

Comment: ya i too miss electropus. you know when I first read "electropus says:" I used to think in a few days there will be a new app that will add electronics tips at the bottom

Comment: @Joby - The decor is not permanent - We get to choose a design, logo, and domain as part of the beta process: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq#sketchy

Comment: He's a ghost in the internet, somewhere out in the aether.

Comment: He should really be a PNG.  I can see the JPG artifacts from here.

Comment: I grabbed that from the images.google.com cache. Free the Electropus! We demand vectors ;-)

Comment: Thanks for posting him Joby, at least he has somewhere to live now, I can pop back & visit, maybe leave him a message :) I've grown quite fond of him - he looks like a quiet and helpful kind of creature.

Comment: Seeing as how we don't have a logo yet, I propose we vote for one:  http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/70/374 . As a previous netizen for chiphacker, I personally think some sort of electropus variant would be nice.  But this is a community thing, and the community should decide as a whole.